# Fast multiplication and modulo operation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to compute:

```
x=(x*a+b)/2 % 2**128
```

many times. x,a,b are 128-bit numbers (choosed randomly). How to do it in fastest way? I thought about numpy, could it help somehow? Now it is about 100 times to slow... Is there way to do it faster? Of course it has to be done separately, step by step, algorithm is more coplicated than this (a,b is changed after few steps), so we can't try to do here any math or fast exponentiation.

Example of more complete code:

```
a=333
b=555
c=777
d=999
x=12345

for i in range(128):
    if x % 2 == 1:
        x=((x * a + b)/2) % 340282366920938463463374607431768211456
    else:
        x=(x * c/2 + d) % 340282366920938463463374607431768211456
    print(x)
```

Comment: Why are you using Python 2? It's past its end-of-life.

Comment: What do you mean by "*compute*"? Are you solving an equation?

Comment: An easy step is to precalculate 2**128.

Comment: What data format or structure are the many `x`s in? And what do you mean about `a` and `b` changing, changing how? You're computing division by 2, modulo 2^128 - I'm assuming you're calculating integer values and don't care about odd numbers getting divided by 2? That also means you might obtain faster results by bit-shifting instead of actually multiplying and dividing, since it's all powers of 2.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  We can't do much with code that you didn't post.

Comment: Please research the Python bit operations.  This is almost certainly faster with shift and mask operations.  Even more, I'm guessing that you're fiddling with a 128-bit linear congruential random number generator.  If so, then posting this questions suggests that you haven't properly researched that paradigm, because then you would already have the bit-wise operations implemented.

Comment: I'm using Python 2, beacuse someone taught me a little bit about it. It is only language that I know so far. Never thought about using Python 3. Compiting means compute x=(5*3+7)/2 mod 4. It is 3. And then solve x=(3*3+7)/2 mod 4. And so on.

Comment: I will give you a example of algorithm in a moment.

Comment: @EricTruett simple and helped a little bit.

Comment: @Prune, it is kind off LCG. I never heard about shift and mask operations in LCG, I will try to find something about it.

Comment: There are C libraries like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) for arbitrary precision math. GMP has several python bindings like [gmpy2](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy2/2.1.0a2/). Worth a try.

Comment: Remember to choose some answer as "best", even if it's something you write yourself.
This allows Stack Overflow to properly archive and retire the question, and I think you get a few points back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have some troubles in that you're doing inherently inefficient operations:128-bit integers are *not* native to most Python implementations, and will incur the penalties of longint operations.  However, you can drop the execution time by about 20% if you use shift & mask operations instead of division and modulus by powers of 2:

```
import timeit

a=333
b=555
c=777
d=999
x=12345
two_128 = 2 ** 128
mask = two_128 - 1

def rng_orig(x):
    for i in range(128):
        if x % 2 == 1:
            x=((x * a + b)/2) % two_128
        else:
            x=(x * c/2 + d) % two_128


def rng_bit(x):
    for i in range(128):
        if x & 1:
            x=((x * a + b) >> 1) & mask
        else:
            x=(x * (c >> 1) + d) & mask


repeat = 100000
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: rng_orig(x), number = repeat))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: rng_bit (x), number = repeat))
```

Timing results:

```
5.1968478000000005
3.965898900000001
```

Comment: Thanks. It works! I read about it somewhere, I figured it could be done in a different way, but didn't know exactly how. Now it seems obvious and trivial.

Comment: Something is wrong here: x=(x * (c >> 1) + d). It is not equal to x=(x * c/2 + d). Also x=(x * (c/2) + d) is not equal to x=(x * c/2 + d). x=(x * c >> 1 + d) is also wrong.

Comment: I think I fixed this. It could be x=((x >> 1)*c + d).

Answer (score 1):

If this is intended to be integer arithmetics, you should use integer divisions.  This will avoid unnecessary conversion to floats. Also, using bitwise operations for the modulo is probably going to be faster.

```
mask128 = 2**128 - 1

x = ( (x*a+b)//2 ) & mask128
```

Comment: Yes, I work only on integers. I will try it.